# Asp Core .Net 3.1 - Automatic binding to Model in Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an ASP .Net Core 3.1 WebApp, and I'm trying to use automatic Model binding, but I'm missing something (basic) in how the conventions are followed

Sales.cshtml:

```
@page
@model foo.Views.Dashboard.SalesModel
<div class="container">
    <h3>@Model.periodMonthSelect</h3>

    <form asp-page="/Dashboards/Sales" method="POST">
        <input name="periodMonthSelect" type="text" value="July 2020"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Sales.cshtml.cs

```
namespace foo.Views.Dashboard
{
    public class SalesModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string periodMonthSelect { get; set; }

    }
}
```

DashboardController.cs

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Sales()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

In the Controller, if I return `new View()` I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` because obviously there is no Model object.  However, if I return `new View(new SalesModel())` the value of the member property `periodMonthSelect` is, of course, null.

I've been trying to find the answer to this, but it's hard to isolate information relevant only to the new .NET Core 3.1 revision.

I've confirmed that the value for `periodMonthSelect` is present in the POST request parameters.

How do I get an automatically populated instance of the Model to be passed to the Razor page?

Comment: If the question is about razor pages, why do you have a controller?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman can't the two be used together?  I want the model-binding feature of Razor pages AND the Routing/Configuration features of Controllers

Comment: Pages are supposed to have handlers, the equivalent of controller actions. I don't believe there is any way to handover a request from a controller action to a page, other than redirecting.